# Spring Data Couchbase: How to rename fields from nested POJOs?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-couchbase

Doc says that the `@Field` annotation can be used to rename a field in an entity. What about fields from nested POJOs that are technically not entities themselves? Consider the following hypothetical example.

```
@Document
public class Person {
    @Id
    private String ssn;
    @Field
    private String name;
    @Field
    private Address address;

    static class Address {
        // how to rename this field to line1?
        private String street;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried @Field(name="line1")

Comment: No, because I'm wondering how far the rename support goes. Can I use the renamed field in queries?

Comment: I don't think I tested this use case during dev so I won't put this as an answer, but it should work with the annotation on the field in the inner class, and the derived queries should use the Java name and get translated to the alias in N1QL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question specifically, you can use `@Field("line1")` for `street` in `Address`.

I have something like this in my project and it works fine (see `descriptions`)

Class 1

```
@Document
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class HotelInfo {
    @Field("hotel_type") @JsonProperty("hotel_type")
    public String hotelType;
    @Field @JsonProperty("images")
    public List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
    @Field @JsonProperty("regions")
    public List<String> regions = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Field @JsonProperty("themes")
    public List<String> themes = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Field @JsonProperty("facilities")
    public List<String> facilities;
    @Field @JsonProperty("descriptions")
    public Descriptions descriptions;
}
```

Class 2

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Descriptions {
    @Field("hotel_information") @JsonProperty("hotel_information")
    public String hotelInformation;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any queries on the renamed field, either written by you or generated by the repository?

Comment: Sorry no, but if I get to try it I'll report back. Also why don't you try it yourself and let us know. Good luck.

Comment: I will try it for sure. I was curious what you did.